# How to create standalone jar file for elastic4s from sources?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to create a standalone jar file from the elastic4s sources on github. I've used `sbt compile` as detailed on the github page, but I can't find the jar file.

How do I use sbt to create the jar file so I can import it into my projects as a dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `compile` task will only compile the project.

```
> help compile
Compiles sources.
```

If you want to create a jar file and use it as a dependency in your project, you have two ways of doing that.

#### Unmanaged dependency (not recommended)

Unmanaged dependency run `+package`, which will create a jar file for each supported scala version, which you can use in your projects as an unmanaged dependency. Copy the `package`-generated jar to `lib` folder in your project.

The jar files will be located in `target/scala-2.11` and `target/scala-2.10`, depending on the Scala version you want to use it with.

#### Publish to Local Repository (recommended yet imperfect)

If you want to include your custom-built elastic4s, as a managed dependency, you have to run `+publishLocal`. This will do the same as above, but additionally it will publish the artifact to your local repository. Assuming you've built it with `version := "1.2.1.1-SNAPSHOT"`, you can include it in your project by just adding:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" %% "elastic4s" % "1.2.1.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

What makes the approach *imperfect* is that once you shared the project on GitHub (or any other project sharing platform), people will have to do `publishLocal` themselves to be able to build your project. The dependency should therefore go to one of the official binary repositories so when a dependency is needed, it's downloaded from Internet. Consult [Publishing](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html).

#### What is the `+` character in front of the commands

The `+` in the commands is for [cross-building](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build.html#cross-building-a-project), if you don't use it the command will be executed only using `scalaVersion` declared in the `build.sbt` of the project.

Comment: Unmanaged dependencies  are easier to start, but harder to maintain in the longer run. Check out this link: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html